# App Check for Expo/React Native app using Firebase JS SDK

Tags: iphone, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-app-check

My Expo based React Native app worked perfectly fine until I added Firebase App Check.

I am using Firebase JS SDK and not React Native Firebase because it is suggested [here](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#usage-with-expo) for cross platform development.

Now how can I get and then send [`context.auth` (link)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/cloud-functions?authuser=0) to Firebase Functions? Or How can I send what Firebase Storage needs to functions manually?

Storage seems to work fine with AppCheck and AppAttest enabled if it's not Enforced but as soon as I enforce it, the app throws a an error every time there is image load from storage that User is not authenticated.

[image]

https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/myapp-4fa75/settings/appcheck

Comment: were you able to solve that?

Comment: @vana22 I was not. I realized App check is meant for native apps only.

Comment: so you didn't use AppChech at all in your App?

Comment: @vana22 correct

Comment: did you then use another App attestation method/provider? Or did you completely not use anything for securing your app?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you can't because the JS SDK uses reCAPTCHA and native apps have to use either SafetyNet (Android) or DeviceCheck or App Attest (iOS).

I think the only option is using [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) instead of JS SDK.

You'd have to use config plugins as described [here](https://rnfirebase.io/#expo) and then configure the `app-check` module as described [here](https://rnfirebase.io/app-check/usage).